# Get PHP output on Batch file

Tags: php, batch-file, output

Found this nowhere else.

I have a batch file which calls a PHP file (php.exe - f file.php).

I'm blocked as i want to pass the PHP output (0 or 1) to the batch file.

Any idea on how to do this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In PHP write:

```php
<?php

echo 'Done';

exit(0);

// Use a value >= 1 for errors
//exit(1);
```

Then use the `%ERRORLEVEL%` variable within the batch file to get the result (error level) from PHP.

```
@echo off

php.exe -f test.php

echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Comment: Okey i was using echo, not return. Thank you!

Comment: Ah sorry, it must be exit(0) or exit(1). I just updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

in the .bat file you can assign any output to the variable like this:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%x IN (`php.exe -f test.php`) do (SET "VARIABLE=%%x")

echo result is %VARIABLE%
```

`VARIABLE` is an arbitrary variable name inside the batch

`usebackq` parameter allows to put whole command in the back quotes (`) and use double quotes (") inside as parameters.